# Chef NOT_IF and ONLY_IF validation issue in Windows recipes

Tags: ruby, powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Im runing this simple recipe block to create a web app in IIS

```
powershell_script "create_site_my_site" do
    code "New-webapppool -name 'My_Web_App'; New-Website -Name 'My_Web_App' -applicationpool 'My_Web_App' -Port '80' -IPAddress * -PhysicalPath 'c:\webs\My_Web_App'  "
    action :run
    not_if "get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq  'My_Web_App' }"
end
```

The problem here its that the NOT_IF part its allways True

```
PS C:\Users\carlos>
PS C:\Users\carlos> get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq 'asdfasdfasdf' }
PS C:\Users\carlos> echo $lastexitcode
1
PS C:\Users\carlos> get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq 'My_Web_App' }

Name        ID    State    Physical Path       Bindings
----        --    -----    -------------       --------
My_Web_App  6     Stopped  c:\webs\My_Web_App  http *:80:    
                                               https *:443:

PS C:\Users\carlos.camacho> echo $lastexitcode
1
```

Now, my question is about how to return True or False in the NOT_IF
depending on my code return value ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of the powershell_out resource from the windows cookbook.

With that you may check the error of a command or not ot if the output is empty.

In your case this should do:

```
only_if powershell_out("get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq  'My_Web_App' }").stdout.empty?
```

Answer (score 5):

```
powershell_script "create_site_my_site" do
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    code "New-webapppool -name 'My_Web_App'; New-Website -Name 'My_Web_App' -applicationpool 'My_Web_App' -Port '80' -IPAddress * -PhysicalPath 'c:\webs\My_Web_App'  "
    action :run
    not_if "get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq  'My_Web_App' }"
end
```

You need to specify `guard_interpreter :powershell_script`. Be aware of [CHEF-1943](https://github.com/opscode/chef/issues/1943) and make sure guard_interpreter is before the guard and do not put the guard in a block.

[powershell_script documentation](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_powershell_script.html#attributes)

An excellent reference on the Chef powershell provider is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNV2jZUjKlc).

Simply using the [IIS cookbook](http://docs.getchef.com/opscode_cookbooks_iis.html) is another option.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Apparently the not_if guard will only execute for powershell if it is contained in a block!

Comment: Filed an issue around powershell guard interpreters as strings: See this issue: https://github.com/opscode/chef/issues/1943

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you're not telling the `not_if` [guard](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html#guard-interpreters) to use the `powershell_script` interperter.

Does this work?

```
powershell_script "create_site_my_site" do
    code "New-webapppool -name 'My_Web_App'; New-Website -Name 'My_Web_App' -applicationpool 'My_Web_App' -Port '80' -IPAddress * -PhysicalPath 'c:\webs\My_Web_App'  "
    action :run
    not_if "$(get-website | where-object { $_.name -eq  'My_Web_App' }).count -gt 0"
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
end
```

Comment: I'm unsure about it, the main problem is that the command always return 1 (according to OP) that's why I was pointing out to powershell_out and testing empty output instead... but once again, changing the guard interpreter could be enought.