# how do I use the output of a shell command as a conditional value in a recipe

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

This is what I want to do:

1. First check if a cert is installed on the server
2. If not installed copy down the pfx to a temp location
3. Install the pfx
4. delete the pfx

How do I do this in a recipe?

Here is some semi-pseudo code:

```
unless "ls Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | ?{$_.Subject -like '*#{cert_name}*'}"

  cookbook_file cert_temp_path do
    source cert_name
  end

  windows_certificate "c:/test/mycert.pfx" do
      pfx_password    'MyPass!'
  end

end
```

How do I execute that line of PS code? Can I call the powershell_script resource directly somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed: [Chef NOT_IF and ONLY_IF validation issue in Windows recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406353/chef-not-if-and-only-if-validation-issue-in-windows-recipes)

I needed the guard_interpreter setting.

Adding this to any resource calls that work with the pfx solve my issue:

```
guard_interpreter :powershell_script
not_if "My powershell code"
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how you would use Chef. Chef requires you rethink in terms of convergent behavior, rather than procedural steps. In this case, your end state would be:

1. Cookbook file for the cert is copied to cache path.
2. Cert is imported.

Trust that `cookbook_file` and `windows_certificate` are idempotent and convergent themselves, meaning they will take care of only acting when needed.

Comment: What I wanted to avoid was having the pfx live in the cache_path on my nodes.

Comment: Any particular reason? Avoiding that will require a fair amount of work depending on how many edge cases you want to plan for and disk space is pretty cheap :)

Comment: Security concern, pfx is encrypted but still includes private key.

Comment: If someone can read an admin-only file, what's the stop them from reading the private key out of the windows cert store directly?